# python3.4 install flask giving error message related to Jinja2 requirement

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am trying to install flask, however I am getting the following error. It seems to be related to Jinja2 however when I do pip list and grep on Jinja you can see I manually installed that already and still getting this error message. Anyone know what is wrong and why I cant install flask

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Jinja2>=2.10 (from flask) (from versions: 2.7.3, 2.8)
No matching distribution found for Jinja2>=2.10 (from flask)
```

Full install message

```
pip install flask
Looking in indexes: http://pyats-pypi.cisco.com/simple
Collecting flask
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/e7/08578774ed4536d3242b14dacb4696386634607af824ea997202cd0edb4b/Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91kB)
    100% |\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588| 92kB 9.3MB/s 
Collecting Werkzeug>=0.14 (from flask)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/c4/12e3e56473e52375aa29c4764e70d1b8f3efa6682bef8d0aae04fe335243/Werkzeug-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (322kB)
    100% |\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588| 327kB 12.5MB/s 
Collecting Jinja2>=2.10 (from flask)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Jinja2>=2.10 (from flask) (from versions: 2.7.3, 2.8)
No matching distribution found for Jinja2>=2.10 (from flask)
```

The Errors seems to be related to Jinja2, however I already have that installed so I'm confused.

```
pip list | grep Jinja2
Jinja2             2.8
```

Comment: try `pip install -U Jinja2`

Comment: Thanks but that did not work. Is there a way to point to a different pypi server? I think this only looks on my works hosted pypi server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `pypi` server is by default pointing to your work hosted server. These are some steps which can help:

1. Uninstall the existing `Jinja2` library using `pip uninstall Jinja2` command
2. Download the `Jinja2` wheel or tar file manually from the [public pypi server](https://pypi.org/project/Jinja2/#files)
3. Install the `Jinja2`library from that file itself. Directly go to the location where have you downloaded the above file and type the following command `pip install Jinja2-2.10.tar.gz` or `pip install Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl` based on which file have you downloaded.

This should install the 2.10 version of `Jinja2` now. Let me know if it did not work.